# Add Cards from child form and also check the validity if none of cards are filled

Tags: angular

I have created a parent form which contains lot of form groups, and form arrays. One of the form array has to receive the object on click of the ADD button from the child form

**Parent Form**

```
this.Employee = this._fb.group({
      list: this._fb.group({
        employeeName: ['existing', [Validators.required]],
        account: [null],
        certificates: [null, [Validators.required]]                
      }),
      dates: this._fb.array([this.createdates()]),
      **createSeminar: this._fb.array([this.createSeminar()])**         
});

this.createSeminar() {
  return _this.fb.array({
      semainarName: [null, [Validators.required]],
      startTime: [null, [Validators.required]],
      endTime: [null, [Validators.required]],
  })
}
```

**Child Form**

**template:**

```
<app-create-seminar [parentForm]="Employee " ></app-executive-info>
```

```
  createSeminarForm():FormArray {
    return this.parentForm.get('createSeminar') as FormArray;
  }
```

[image]

Here create Seminar is the child form, which contains the ADD button. On click of the ADD button i have to add new objects to the Create Seminar Array and also I have display it as a card below the child form

> Problem Facing:

What I did was,

1. I shared the parent form with the child form and accessed the createSeminar in child form and created a getter and iterated it as an array.
2. But as per the requirement I should not require this to be iterated, but instead i have to get input from the child form and update the `createSeminar` Array in parent form. And also if none of the values are inserted in the parent form `CreateSeminar` Array then I should not allow the form to be submitted.
3. I have the possibility to create the separate form and validate it from the parent form if required, but i don't want to do that, instead create one form parent form and just reuse it.

Please give me some idea on how to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you post the templates? Also, it'd be better if you provide a stackblitz demo.

Comment: I have created a stackbliz for your reference, Please have a look into this. https://angular-qykaha.stackblitz.io

Comment: Make the stackblitz editable so we can see the full source.

Answer (score 1):

In parent component:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<form [formGroup]="employee">
    <h2>Parent Form</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-9">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Employee Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="employeeName"
      [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': submitted && employee.controls.employeeName.errors }">
    </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Account Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="accountName"   [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': submitted && employee.controls.accountName.errors }">
    </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Certificate</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="Certificate"
      [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': submitted && employee.controls.Certificate.errors }">
    </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="disable()" (click)="onSubmitForm()">Submit</button>&nbsp;
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="reset()">Reset</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <pre>{{ employee.value | json}}</pre>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <seminar-details [formGroup]="employee" (enable)="enableSubmit($event)">
                        </seminar-details>
                    </div>
                </div>
</form>
```

In TS:

```
  employee: FormGroup;
  submitted: boolean = false;
  enable: boolean= false;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.intializeForm();
  }

  private intializeForm() {

    this.employee = this.formBuilder.group({
      employeeName: ["", [Validators.required]],
      accountName: ["", [Validators.required]],
      Certificate: ["", [Validators.required]],
      seminarDetails: this.formBuilder.array([])
    });
  }

  createSeminar(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      seminarName: [null, [Validators.required]],
      presenterName: [null, [Validators.required]],
      startTime: [null, [Validators.required]],
      endTime: [null, [Validators.required]]
    });
  }

  reset() {
    this.employee.reset();
  }

  onSubmitForm() {
    this.submitted = true;
    if (this.employee.valid) {
      console.log("form is valid");
    }
    return false;
  }

  disable() {
    return !(
      (this.enable==true) && (this.employee.valid) 
    );
  }

  enableSubmit(value){
    this.enable=value;
  }
```

In Child component:

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="seminarDetailsForm">
    <h2>Child Form</h2>
    <p>On clicking add button here, the object should get added to the parent seminar array. By default the array will
        not contain any object untill it is been added from the child form.</p>
    <p>If nothing is added, then the parent form will not be allowed to submit.</p>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Seminar Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="seminarName">
    </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Presenter Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="presenterName" >
    </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">startTime</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="startTime" >
    </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">endTime</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="endTime">
    </div>

                    <button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="disable()" (click)="addSeminar()">Add</button>

                    <p>The added cards should be added below simultaniously on adding the form up.</p>
                    <div class="card">
                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                            <li class="list-group-item"
                                *ngFor="let item of form.get('seminarDetails').value; let i = index">
                                {{item?.seminarName}} |
                                {{item?.presenterName}} |
                                {{item?.startTime}} |
                                {{item?.endTime}}
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
</form>
```

In TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, EventEmitter, Output } from "@angular/core";
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  FormControl,
  FormArray,
  Validators
} from "@angular/forms";
import { Subscription } from "rxjs";
@Component({
  selector: "seminar-details",
  templateUrl: "./seminar-details.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./seminar-details.component.css"]
})
export class SeminarDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;
  seminarDetailsForm: FormGroup;
  @Output() enable=new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  @Input() set formGroup(form: any) {
    this.form = form;
  }
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.seminarDetailsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      seminarName: [null, [Validators.required]],
      presenterName: [null, [Validators.required]],
      startTime: [null, [Validators.required]],
      endTime: [null, [Validators.required]]
    });
  }

  addSeminar() {
    (this.form.get("seminarDetails") as FormArray).push(
      this.seminarDetailsForm
    );
    this.enable.emit(true);
  }

  disable(): boolean {
    return !(
      this.checkIfValue(this.form.get("employeeName").value) &&
      this.checkIfValue(this.form.get("accountName").value) &&
      this.checkIfValue(this.form.get("Certificate").value) && this.seminarDetailsForm.valid
    );
  }

  checkIfValue(data) {
    return (data != null && data != undefined && data.toString().trim() != "");
  }
}
```

I had to make a couple of changes. I passing the employee form to child and initially the seminarDetails is set as empty array. Then on click add button, I am pushing that to employee form from child component.

I think all 3 scenarios you mentioned are covered.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a single formGroup of CreateSeminar to child component.

```
addSeminar(){
   (this.employee.get('seminarDetails') as FormArray).push(
    this.createSeminar());
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let seminarDetail of employee['controls'].seminarDetails['controls']; let i = index;">
      <seminar-details [formGroup]="seminarDetail" (onClickAddSeminar)="addSeminar()"></seminar-details>
</div>
```

Then if user click from child component you can emit to parent component and add a new formGroup in parent component.

Here is working example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b4dw1x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)